# How can I detect logical changes

Tags: r

For example, I have the following:

```
a<-c(1,1,0,0,1,1,0)
```

The output must be:

```
0 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

Is there another way to do this operation instead of using for loop?

Comment: `c(0, abs(diff(a)))`

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe you could use

```
c(0, as.numeric(!head(a,-1) == a[-1]))
```

when a is not a (0,1) vector